# Unable to load information from the model, Error: Driver not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have created a  CRUD application in laravel, but when i am trying to get the information, getting Error "Could not find Driver", when i have already install the all the required driver to run Laravel, i have also enable the pdo_mysql from php.ini, but unable to find the solution:
Here are the my codes:
my Model: Product.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    //

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'detail'
    ];
}
```

My ProductController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

        $products = Product::all();        
        return view('products.index',compact('products', $products));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
        return view('products.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'detail' => 'required',
        ]);

        Product::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('products.index')
                        ->with('success','Product created successfully.');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Product $product)
    {
        return view('products.show',compact('product'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Product $product)
    {
        return view('products.edit',compact('product'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'detail' => 'required',
        ]);

        $product->update($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('products.index')
                        ->with('success','Product updated successfully');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Product $product)
    {
        //
        $product->delete();

        return redirect()->route('products.index')
                        ->with('success','Product deleted successfully');
    }
}
```

my .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=l5_project
DB_USERNAME=localuser
DB_PASSWORD=R@5gull@
```

my php.ini file:

```
;extension=bz2
;extension=curl
;extension=fileinfo
;extension=gd2
;extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=interbase
;extension=ldap
;extension=mbstring
;extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=odbc
;extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
;extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop
```

Is there anything that i am missing from the codes. Please help me to find the issue with shared code.

Comment: Do you get any more information or is that the only message you get?

Comment: this may help https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/could-not-find-driver-error-in-laravel-55

Comment: @Jerodev, i am getting error: 
Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException
could not find driver (SQL: select * from `products`)
Previous exceptions
could not find driver (0)

Comment: @manu, i have checked all the possible way to resolve the issue, but unable to find what is exact issue with  my code.

Comment: As the error tells you, this is not a code issue, this has to do with ur driver and *server* configuration

Comment: I have configure driver correctly while installation of php and mysql.

Answer (score 1):

i think your errors in this file "php.ini"
so install php7.1-pdo php7.1-mysql
or download default for it from github